# how to detect previous installed versions of windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I just bought an old computer, which had a pirated version of Windows7 on it, so I installed Ubuntu instead, which of course is free. But one guy from Microsoft says that they can detect previous installation of Windows and this may lead to legal issues.

Is this is real? Can Microsoft detect previous installations after a formatting?

Comment: If you fully formatted disk and then fully write disk any information - only miracle can detect pirated Windows. )

Answer (score 1):

Just to get this out of the way: I am not a lawyer.

I don't see how there can be any legal issues for you if you've removed the offending pirated copy of Windows. As far as that goes I'd consider yourself covered.
Detecting previous installs: my suspicion is that it'd be more likely them finding out your unique hardware IDs and matching that with whatever versions of Windows may have "phoned home" to Microsoft. However, my understanding is that pirated copies are typically modified to remove this capability. There's no other way to detect previous installs, at least as far as I know, on a fully formatted drive.

Where did you find this Microsoft guy? Honestly, this sounds more like someone is just screwing with you more than anything.